# OAuth token for REST API call to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 using service principal

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-storage, azure-rest-api, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm working on an application (one of the core microservices) which will call the Azure ADLS Gen 2 to store files (in a filesystem) for further processing by other components.

I'm trying to obtain an OAuth token for the authentication purposes by calling Azure authentication endpoint using the preliminarily created service principal.

The PowerShell code I'm using to create a service principal:

```
Add-AzAccount -Subscription <SUBSCRIPTION ID>
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName <PRINCIPAL NAME>
Sleep 20
New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ApplicationId
$sp.ApplicationId
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($sp.Secret)
$UnsecureSecret = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$UnsecureSecret
```

I'm using the values of `$sp.ApplicationId` as < Azure AD application client ID>
 and `$UnsecureSecret` as < Azure AD application client secret>.

The Azure AD application is then configured with API permissions:

[image]

I've added the Azure AD application as a STORAGE BLOB DATA CONTRIBUTOR to the storage account's IAM blade.

Next, I'm going yo obtain an OAuth token.
Below are the calls I've made using Postman:

GET

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/token
```

Headers

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request body

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <Azure AD application client ID>
client_secret: <Azure AD application client secret>
scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

After this call I'm able to get the successful response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",  
    "expires_in": "3600",  
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",  
    "expires_on": "1574686915",  
    "not_before": "1574683015",  
    "resource": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",  
    "access_token": "eyJ0eX<..>" . 
}
```

Then I'm trying to create a filesystem by using the following request:

PUT

```
https://<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>.dfs.core.windows.net/<FILESYSTEM NAME>?resource=filesystem
```

Headers

```
Authorization: Bearer <JWT token>
x-ms-date: Mon, 25 Nov 2019 12:00:00 GMT
x-ms-version: 2019-02-02
```

And constantly getting the following error:

```
        {
            "error": {
                "code": "InvalidAuthenticationInfo",
                "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request.   
    Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
\nRequestId:a6bf42d7-a01f-0006-1d88-a304da000000\nTime:2019-11-25T12:05:32.3049492Z"
            }
        }
```

I have tried different scopes but it doesn't help:

```
https://dfs.core.windows.net/.default
https://blob.core.windows.net/.default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the `Contributor` RBAC role is enough, no need to add any `API permission`, the issue was caused by the way you request the token, when using the `v1.0` endpoint, you need to use `resource: https://storage.azure.com/`.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <Azure AD application client ID>
client_secret: <Azure AD application client secret>
resource: https://storage.azure.com/
```

Or you can change the request URL to `v2.0` endpoint, it will also work.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <Azure AD application client ID>
client_secret: <Azure AD application client secret>
scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

Test:

[image]

Comment: Well, I should have guessed )
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're my hero.  This was killing me trying to upgrade from DLS Gen1 to Gen2.  I knew the account was fine because it worked with the Gen1 calls but not the Gen2 calls.  Changed to the new resource URI and it just worked.  THANKS!!!